# Inject/use Angular Service in Toastr.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, toastr

I've recently started using the Toastr.js library to display alerts on an angular website. I use an Angular service to connect to the database and pull or post alerts, then send the resulting alerts to the toastr service, which works perfectly. I want to customize the library so that when a user clicks the close icon on a toast, the toastr service will send an update to the database. I have the relevant code in place in my customized toastr.js, but I don't know how to use the pre-existing Angular service to make this call.

How can I inject/reference/use the pre-existing Angular service into toastr.js so I can use it's methods to post to the database? It doesn't use Angular, and is wrapped in require syntax.

For reference, toastr.js looks something like the below:

```
(function (define) {
    define(['jquery'], function ($) {
        return (function () {
            //code stuff here, functions
        });
}(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define : function (deps, factory) {
    if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) { //Node
        module.exports = factory(require('jquery'));
    } else {
        window.toastr = factory(window.jQuery);
    }
}));
```

Comment: check the below answer which has code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`angular-toastr`](https://github.com/Foxandxss/angular-toastr) Plugin.

```
app.controller('foo', function($scope, toastr) {
  toastr.info('We are open today from 10 to 22', 'Information');
});
```

Below is how you can edit the Configuration of toastr and customise

```
app.config(function(toastrConfig) {
  angular.extend(toastrConfig, {
    allowHtml: false,
    closeButton: false,
    closeHtml: '<button>&times;</button>',
    extendedTimeOut: 1000,
    iconClasses: {
      error: 'toast-error',
      info: 'toast-info',
      success: 'toast-success',
      warning: 'toast-warning'
    },  
    messageClass: 'toast-message',
    onHidden: null,
    onShown: null,
    onTap: null,
    progressBar: false,
    tapToDismiss: true,
    templates: {
      toast: 'directives/toast/toast.html',
      progressbar: 'directives/progressbar/progressbar.html'
    },
    timeOut: 5000,
    titleClass: 'toast-title',
    toastClass: 'toast'
  });
});
```

#### Toast with custom HTML

```
toastr.info('<input type="checkbox" checked> Success!', 'With HTML', {
  allowHtml: true
});
```